# Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'label'

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to take values from 5 text boxes and calculate the total of those 5 boxes and enter them into another box.  I believe I have everything correct until I try to move the value of those boxes into the last box.  I get this error:
Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'label'

The program runs fine until line is entered.  I am just trying to figure out how to transfer the calculation into this box.  How do I convert the 'Integer' into the 'Label', or change the format of the 'Label'?  I am 2 weeks into this VB class so this all seems like hieroglyphics

Public Class MainForm

```
'This code allows the exit button to close the application
Private Sub exitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
'This code allows the Calculate button to sum all boxes and enter them into the Total box.
Private Sub calcButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calcButton.Click
    Dim intNum1 As Integer
    Dim intNum2 As Integer
    Dim intNum3 As Integer
    Dim intNum4 As Integer
    Dim intNum5 As Integer
    Dim intNum6 As Integer
    Dim intNum7 As Integer
    Dim intAns1 As Integer
    Dim intAns2 As Integer

    intNum1 = Val(monTextBox)
    intNum2 = Val(tuesTextBox)
    intNum3 = Val(wedTextBox)
    intNum4 = Val(thursTextBox)
    intNum5 = Val(friTextBox)
    intNum6 = Val(satTextBox)
    intNum7 = Val(sunTextBox)
    intAns1 = Val(totalWeekdayLabel)
    intAns2 = Val(totalWeekendLabel)
    intAns1 = intNum1 + intNum2 + intNum3 + intNum4 + intNum5
    totalWeekdayLabel = intAns1
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub calcButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calcButton.Click
    Dim intNum1 As Integer
    Dim intNum2 As Integer
    Dim intNum3 As Integer
    Dim intNum4 As Integer
    Dim intNum5 As Integer
    Dim intAns1 As Integer

    intNum1 = monTextBox.Text
    intNum2 = tuesTextBox.Text
    intNum3 = wedTextBox.Text
    intNum4 = thursTextBox.Text
    intNum5 = friTextBox.Text

    intAns1 = intNum1 + intNum2 + intNum3 + intNum4 + intNum5
    totalWeekdayLabel.Text = intAns1
End Sub
```

When setting the variables you'll want to use TextBox.Text to get the text value. Same with setting the text in the label, you want to use label.Text to set the value.

Good luck in your class <3